# Java Null Pointer Exception error

Tags: java, servlets

Everytime I click a link to my other pages, I get a Null Pointer Exception error, I don't know what's the problem.

Here's the error

```
05-Jul-2014 17:27:25.941 SEVERE [http-nio-8084-exec-14] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [itemServlet] in context with path [/servlet] threw exception
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.etc.servlet.itemServlet.showProductList(itemServlet.java:172)
    at com.etc.servlet.itemServlet.doPost(itemServlet.java:94)
    at com.etc.servlet.itemServlet.doGet(itemServlet.java:67)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:301)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1015)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:652)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1575)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1533)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Here's the partial code of the servlet that throws the NullPointerException

```
public class itemServlet extends HttpServlet {

private memberDao usrdao = new memberDao();
private itemDao itmdao = new itemDao();
private noticeDao ntcdao=new noticeDao();
private articleDao atcdao=new articleDao();
private List<item> listItm;
private List<notice> listNtc;
private List<article> listAtc;
private List<member> listUsr;
private List<item> listpiece;
/**
 * Constructor of the object.
 */
public itemServlet() {
    super();
}

/**
 * Destruction of the servlet. <br>
 */
public void destroy() {
    super.destroy(); // Just puts "destroy" string in log
    // Put your code here
}

/**
 * The doGet method of the servlet. <br>
 *
 * This method is called when a form has its tag value method equals to get.
 * 
 * @param request the request send by the client to the server
 * @param response the response send by the server to the client
 * @throws ServletException if an error occurred
 * @throws IOException if an error occurred
 */
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    doPost(request,response);
}

/**
 * The doPost method of the servlet. <br>
 *
 * This method is called when a form has its tag value method equals to post.
 * 
 * @param request the request send by the client to the server
 * @param response the response send by the server to the client
 * @throws ServletException if an error occurred
 * @throws IOException if an error occurred
 */
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    //1 中文处理
    request.setCharacterEncoding("gbk");
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=gbk");

    //2 读取参数op
    String op = request.getParameter("op");

    //3 根据op调用不同的业务方法
    if("add".equals(op)){
        additem(request,response);//
    }else if("findall".equals(op)){
        showProductList(request,response);//展现所有商品
    }else if("finddetail".equals(op)){
        showProductDetail(request,response);//展现商品的细节
    }else if("addcart".equals(op)){
        addcart(request,response);//添加购物车
    }

}

    private void addcart(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)throws           ServletException, IOException//展示商品细节
{
    int itmID=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("itemID"));
    System.out.println("获取本页的商品编号"+itmID);
    item additem = itmdao.findbyitmmID(itmID);
    HttpSession session =request.getSession();
    if(request.getSession().getAttribute("listpiece")==null){

        listpiece=new ArrayList<item>();
        listpiece.add(additem);
        System.out.println("listpiece为空。将查到的商品作为单件加入listpiece的列表");
        session.setAttribute("listpiece", listpiece);           
    }
    else{
        List<item> listpiece=(List<item>)      request.getSession().getAttribute("listpiece");
        listpiece.add(additem);
        System.out.println("listpiece不为空，将查到的商品作为单件加入listpiece的列表");
        session.setAttribute("listpiece", listpiece);
    }
    if(listItm==null)
    {
        response.getWriter().print("查询失败！");
        return;                     
    }

    int itid = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("itemID"));

    for(item it:listItm)
    {
        if(itid==it.getItemID())//找出该对象
        {
            request.setAttribute("it", it);
              request.getRequestDispatcher("../itemdetail.jsp").forward(request, response);
            return;             
        }

    }
}

private void showProductDetail(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse     response)throws ServletException, IOException//展示商品细节
{
    if(listItm==null)
    {
        response.getWriter().print("查询失败！");
        return;                     
    }

    int itid = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("itemID"));

    for(item it:listItm)
    {
        if(itid==it.getItemID())//找出该对象
        {
            request.setAttribute("it", it);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("../itemdetail.jsp").forward(request, response);
            return;             
        }

    }
}

private void showProductList(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException, IOException//商品成列
{
    listItm = itmdao.findAll();
    listNtc = ntcdao.findSix();
    listAtc = atcdao.findTen();
    request.setAttribute("listNtc", listNtc);
    request.setAttribute("listAtc", listAtc);
    request.setAttribute("listItm", listItm);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("../showlist.jsp").forward(request, response);
}

private void additem(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException, IOException//添加一件新的商品
{
    //1 图片上传
    SmartUpload sm = new SmartUpload();
    sm.initialize(this.getServletConfig(), request, response);
    sm.setAllowedFilesList("jpg,jpeg,png,gif");

    try 
    {
        sm.upload();
        sm.save("/pic");//在pic路径下按原来的名字进行保存
    } catch (SmartUploadException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        response.getWriter().print("上传失败！添加失败！");
        return;                     
    }

    //2 读取表单的其他数据，插入数据库

    String itemName = sm.getRequest().getParameter("itemName");
   float itemPrice = Float.parseFloat(sm.getRequest().getParameter("price"));
     float itemPrice = Float.parseFloat(sm.getRequest().getParameter("itemPrice"));     
     String itemStatus = sm.getRequest().getParameter("itemStatus");        
     String itemBrief = sm.getRequest().getParameter("itemBrief");      
     int typeID =Integer.parseInt(sm.getRequest().getParameter("typeID"));
     item newitem = new item(-1,itemName,itemPrice,itemStatus,itemBrief,typeID );

    if (!itmdao.add(newitem))
    {
        response.getWriter().print("添加失败！");
        return;         
    }
    request.getRequestDispatcher("itemServlet?op=findall").forward(request, response);
}

/**
 * Initialization of the servlet. <br>
 *
 * @throws ServletException if an error occurs
 */
public void init() throws ServletException {
    // Put your code here
}

}
```

Is it possible that the null pointer comes from the database?

itmDao.findall()

```
public List<item> findAll() 
{
    System.out.println("itemDao的findAll被调用");
    List<item> list = new ArrayList();
    ResultSet rs =  DBUtils.doQuery("select * from itemTable  order by itemID desc");
    try {
        if (rs == null)
            return list;
        while (rs.next()) {
            item item = new item(rs.getInt("itemID"),
                    rs.getString("itemName"),      rs.getFloat("itemPrice"),rs.getString("itemStatus"),rs.getString("itembrief")
                    ,rs.getInt("typeID"));
            list.add(item);

        }
    } catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        try 
        {
            DBUtils.close(rs, rs.getStatement(), rs.getStatement()
                    .getConnection());
        } catch (Exception e2) 
        {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return list;

}
```

ntddao.findsix()

```
  public List<notice> findSix() //用在首页的  查找前六条的公告
{
    System.out.println("noticeDao的findSix函数被调用");
    List<notice> list = new ArrayList();
    ResultSet rs =  DBUtils.doQuery("select * from notice order by ntID desc");
    try {
        if (rs == null)
            return list;
        int i=1;
        while (rs.next()&&i<=6) {
            notice notice = new notice(rs.getInt("ntID"),
                    rs.getString("ntTitle"),    rs.getString("ntTime"),rs.getString("ntText"),rs.getInt("adID"));
            list.add(notice);
            i++;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        try 
        {
            DBUtils.close(rs, rs.getStatement(), rs.getStatement()
                    .getConnection());
        } catch (Exception e2) 
        {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return list;
```

}

atcdao.findten()

```
public List<article> findTen() //用在首页的  查找前10条的公告
{
    System.out.println("articleDao的findTen函数被调用");
    List<article> list = new ArrayList();
    ResultSet rs =  DBUtils.doQuery("select * from article order by atID desc");
    try {
        if (rs == null)
            return list;
        int i=1;
        while (rs.next()&&i<=10) {
            article article = new article(rs.getInt("atID"),
                    rs.getString("atTitle"), rs.getString("atPic"),rs.getString("atTime"),rs.getString("atText"),rs.getInt("adID"));
            list.add(article);
            i++;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        try 
        {
            DBUtils.close(rs, rs.getStatement(), rs.getStatement()
                    .getConnection());
        } catch (Exception e2) 
        {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return list;

}
```

Comment: **Please stick to Java naming conventions**. Classes are in `PascalCase` - `itemSevlet` is wrong. As are all your other class names. Which is line `172`?

Comment: NPE means that you are calling method on reference assigned to null. You should assign value to reference before calling method on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path you supply to `getRequestDispatcher` must be within the current servlet context.  That means that you can't use something like `"../showlist.jsp"`.  You are going to have to organise your directory structure differently.

Comment: By within current servlet context do you mean that either the jsp or the servlet has to be in the same folder?

Comment: I would put the JSPs in a subfolder called jsp.  But put that folder in a location where you don't need the "../" to reference it.  You may have to experiment a little to see what works with the way you've set up your application.

Answer (score 0):

Could you check for null the following objects there please?

```
listItm = itmdao.findAll();
listNtc = ntcdao.findSix();
listAtc = atcdao.findTen();
```

I assume one(or more) of them is null, so the setAttribute throwing an exception.

Otherwise I strongly recommend to not enforce to use fields in a servlet that runs as a singleton in the memory and multiple user requests can break the coherence in your data.
I'm talking about these fields:

```
private List<item> listItm;
private List<notice> listNtc;
private List<article> listAtc;
private List<member> listUsr;
private List<item> listpiece;
```

My other recommendation is to follow java naming convention. For example change the first character of your class to capital: itemServlet -> ItemServlet.

This is the more standard way and helps us to understand your code better :)

Comment: No, this isn't the issue.  Those fields are all initialised with new objects, and there's no code that can reset them to null.

Comment: listItm or listNtc or listAtc can be null if the dao can return null.

The second part of my answer is about a potential concurrency issue not the NPE

Comment: Hello, I have provided my code for itmdao.findAll(), ntcdao.findSix(), and atcdao.findTen(), I am in a bit of a hurry, so I will change my code if I have the time, really sorry!

Comment: @Lexandro Yes, those variables can be null; but that won't lead to the NPE.  The OP asked about the NPE, and your answer doesn't explain the NPE.  The reason for the NPE is the location of the JSP - it has nothing to do with the DAOs.

Comment: You're right. Now I see in the DAO code, it never returns null. I had a wrong assumption :) I marked your answer with +1